# TFS Branch Merge on different branches

Tags: tfs

I've the following structure on TFS:

> $Base
>
> ```
>  - $Dev Branch 1
>
>  - $Integration Branch 2
> ```

I would like to merge the changes on Dev Branch 1 to Integration Branch 2 so that build guys can kickoff Hudson build of this Integration Branch.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Team, and when I try to merch Dev Branch1 I can only see Base on Target Branch drop down.

Could anyone please advise how and if it's possible to merge between Dev and Integration branches above.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason for using Hudson instead of the built-in Team Build?

Comment: TFS is quiet new to the organization i.e. being migrated from VSS. So Hudson will eventually be replaced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this but neither are that great. For the first method you will need to install the [TFS 2010 power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)

1. Use a shelve set. Start the merge from dev to base, resolve any conflicts. Do not check in the merge, instead shelve the changes. Then from the command line use `tfpt unshelve "my shelve set" /migrate /source:$/teamProject/dev /target:$/teamProject/integration`. This will migrate the shelved changes to the integration branch without having to commit the changes to the base branch.
2. Perform a baseless merge between dev and integration. You can do this by using the command `tf merge $/teamProject/dev $/teamProject/integration /baseless /recursive` once the baseless merge has established a branching relationship then you can do further merges through the UI. Be warned though that a baseless merge won't know about any files or folders that have been renamed or moved so you will need to make sure you take this in to account.

Personally I'd go for option 1 if it's a one time thing. If it's going to be something you think you'll need to do regularly then I'd do the baseless merge when all 3 branches are in sync I.e. just after you've merged from dev to base to integration. This should minimise any issues with the baseless merge.

You might also want to take a look at your branching strategy so that you don't need to perform complex merging operations very often. If you use an integration branch then it should have a direct relationship with any branches you need to integrate. Check out the [ALM rangers branching guidance](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can only merge to where the branch was created from. You would have to merge from Dev to Base and then again from Base to Integration.

If you want to merge from Dev to Integration directly then your Integration branch should be created as a branch from Dev not Base.